# Net framework 3.5. Takes too long to run application

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-3.5

I am developing an application in NET 3.5 C# and WPF and from the beginning it took AGES to run at most machines.. Only on my core i7 machine runs within 2-3 seconds...
At most pcs tested it takes about 30 seconds to load!!! even from the start when it contained only a button and no code just to load the application...
Can i do something for this?

Comment: Upgrade all machines to have a decent graphics card?

Comment: not possible.The application must run at old computers... Windows XP 256 ram stuff (dont ask me why WPF i was against it ,but i was forced to use it)

Comment: if you were forced - why should you be responsible for that then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are experiencing the same problem with an empty application (no dependencies, single button, etc), then there is nothing you can do.  The .NET runtime isn't small.  Your options are:

- Use something else (native / GDI+)
- Upgrade your machines
- Try to optimize the machines themselves (turn off services/anything else that is gobbling up RAM/CPU power)
- Make sure other .NET apps are running on the machine, so it is constantly in memory :)
- Live with the performance